# Connect all points of a 3D graph with the shortest path

Tags: graph-theory, geometric-graph

I have a collection of $(x, y, z)$ points that are all contained in a $1 \times 1 \times 1$ cube with $(x, y, z) \in [0, 1]^3$. I need to find the shortest path to cross all the points. This looks like an *minimum spanning path problem* in 3D but there are a few tricks that change the problem a little bit:

1. The planes $(z = 0)$ and $(z = 1)$ are connected, i.e. the points $(2, 3, 0.01)$ and $(2, 3, 0.97)$ are very close and only $0.04$ apart.
2. I can only move parallel to the Ox, Oy and Oz axes.
3. **It is not so much the distance that matters as the number of displacements** (one displacement means one move on one axis, i.e. I may need 1, 2, or 3 moves for going from one point to another).

Does anyone know of an existing or adaptable algorithm that could address this problem?

Comment: (3) makes (1) irrelevant, right? Can you clarify what the "spanning tree" set should minimize?

Comment: Are you looking for a path or a tree?

Comment: (3) makes (1) irrelevant: true, but this property may be important to notice (or may be not). I am looking for a path crossing all the points that can start from each one of them, that minimizes the number of displacements

Comment: So are you looking for a Hamiltonian path?